# using twitter API to search tweets

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am trying to search tweets based on location using twitter API
essentially I want to use the link 1.1/search/tweets.json?q=......
IT went well tell the point of parsing or exploding the results
I wasn't able to read the tweet text...don't know why

I successes using different approach
here is my code

```
<?php
require 'tmhOAuth.php'; // Get it from: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

 // Use the data from http://dev.twitter.com/apps to fill out this info
 // notice the slight name difference in the last two items)
 $file = fopen("data.txt","w");
 $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
 'consumer_key' => 'key',
'consumer_secret' => 'key',
'user_token' => 'key', //access token
'user_secret' => 'key' //access token secret
    ));
   if ($_GET['twitter_path']) { $twitter_path = $_GET['twitter_path']; }  else {
$twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/user_timeline';
   }

    $http_code = $connection->request('GET', $connection->url($twitter_path), array ('screen_name' =>'latimesquakes'));
    if ($http_code === 200) { // if everything's good
$response = strip_tags($connection->response['response']);
$twitFeed = json_decode($response, true);
if ($_GET['callback']) { // if we ask for a jsonp callback function
    echo $_GET['callback'],'(', $response,');';
} else {
foreach ($twitFeed as $tweet)
{

    echo fwrite($file,$tweet['text']."\n");
   echo $tweet['text'].'<br>';
   }
  }
}
  else {
echo "Error ID: ",$http_code, "<br>\n";
echo "Error: ",$connection->response['error'], "<br>\n";
 }
```

but this code won't allow me to search base on location
so anybody can suggest how to use this code to search base on location
or suggest a code to use 1.1/search/tweets.json? to search based on location
my project is based on getting tweets about LA earthquakes
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't include your damn API keys!

Comment: Please revoke your keys if you haven’t already. Removing revisions can only do so much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using a library for it, for example https://github.com/dg/twitter-php. (i used it once and worked very nice)

Comment: so I just need to include this file to my code. and the json_decode will work....?? so the foreach will accept it

Comment: @user3385409 sorry, but it was paid project and its only in private repository :(